# fetch send formdata and recieve it from php

Tags: php, fetch, send

Hello srry for bad english, i'm trying to insert some formdata to my sql database with fetch request, the row was added and the id counts +1, but theres no extra data added to the columns "nomtar","destar",etc

JS function on submit form:

```
function enviarDatos(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nomtar = document.getElementById('nomtar').value;
    var destar = document.getElementById('destar').value;
    var usu2tar = document.getElementById('usu2tar').value;
    var fectar = document.getElementById('fectar').value;
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('nomtar',nomtar);
    formData.append('destar',destar);
    formData.append('usu2tar',usu2tar);
    formData.append('fectar',fectar);
    fetch('servicios/agregar.php',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    }).then(response => {
      if(response.ok){
        console.log("datos enviados");
      }
      else{
        console.log("datos no enviados");
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      });
  }
```

agregar.php FILE:

```
    <?php
  session_start();
  include('conexion.php');
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

  $nomtar=$data['nomtar'];
  $destar=$data['destar'];
  $fectar=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data['fectar']));
  $usu1tar=$_SESSION['idusu'];
  $usu2tar=$data['usu2tar'];
  $query="select idusu from usuario where nombre='$usu2tar'";
  $result1=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  if($result1){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){

        $idusu=$row['idusu'];

    }
  }


  $sql="INSERT INTO tarea(usu1tar,usu2tar,nomtar,destar,fectar,esttar) VALUES('$usu1tar','$idusu','$nomtar','$destar','$fectar',1)";
  $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));


  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? What values do the variables have? Regardless, this is not how to write database code. Please look up **prepared statements,** you will make your code more secure and quite possibly fix your problem.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to convert your form data to JSON. `Fetch` understands `FormData` directly.

Change this line

```
body: JSON.stringify(formData)
```

to this:

```
  body: formData
```

Now your PHP code can extract the incoming data from `$_POST` without having to read `php://input`

```
    <?php
  session_start();
  include('conexion.php');
  // remove line that reads php://input here.

  $nomtar=$_POST['nomtar'];
  $destar=$_POST['destar'];
  $fectar=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['fectar']));
  $usu1tar=$_SESSION['idusu'];
  $usu2tar=$_POST['usu2tar'];
// rest of code follows
```

That should get you going, but be aware, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Once you get this fixed you should refactor your code to use prepared statements.

Note: `FormData` can extract data directly from a form without you extracting it field by field. `let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('formId'))` will do it in one operation.